# Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()

Tags: java, heap-memory

Does Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() return the free heap memory space or heap + non-heap memory space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory%28%29) says:

> @return an approximation to the total amount of memory currently available for future allocated objects, measured in bytes.

This means heap space.

Answer (score 1):

its free heap memory space. and it will be in bytes

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware its the free heap memory, it certainly is on mobile Java.